# In a commutative ring $R$ if, for every $a\in R$, the smallest ideal containing $a$ is equal to $Ra$ then $R$ has identity?

Tags: commutative-algebra, rngs

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring such that, for every $a\in R$, the smallest ideal containing $a$ is equal to $Ra$. Does $R$ have identity?

I did this when $R$ has at least one non-zero divisor then it's true.

But I can't guess  that  it is true in general case.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Consider $\oplus_{i=1}^\infty F_2$ meaning the subset of $\prod_{i=1}^\infty F_2$ whose elements are only finitely nonzero. And $F_2$ means the field of two elements.